# How to access a library from another library?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, okhttp, android-glide

I am creating a library that needs to use the Glide and OkHttp libraries.

My library works perfectly if I include these libraries in my library. However, to keep my library size small, I would ideally like to not include Glide and OkHttp in my library but rather require that the app using my library include Glide and OkHttp. My library would then reference these libraries in the app.

Is this possible? How should I do this?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I think you should put your comment into answer field, since it's most appropriate solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `compileOnly` in your library gradle file